# How to order Rails Collection with a scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given a scope that determines if a model is active or not..

```
def active?
    return false unless published_at && expires_at && id

    DateTime.now.between? published_at, expires_at
  end
```

How do you use this scope, with other scopes, to sort a collection?

This doens't seem to work.

```
@posts = current_user.posts
        .includes(:orgs)
        .order(:active?)
        .order(created_at: :desc)
```

Comment: Do you have any example input/output records that show how you want the result to be ordered? Only providing the necessary fields would be enough (*id*, *published_at* and *expires_at*). For example: `1 | NULL | NULL`, `2 | 2019-01-01 | NULL`, `3 | 2019-01-02 | 2021-01-01`, etc (assuming the headers `id | published_at | expires_at`)

Answer (score 4):

Your code doesn't work because you're returning a `boolean` in both cases. And a `boolean` can't be chained.

Instead, you need to return an `ActiveRecord_Relation` that can be chained. So, perhaps something more like:

```
def active?
  return none unless published_at && expires_at && id
  where("published_at <= ? AND expires_at >= ?", DateTime.now, DateTime.now)
end
```

TBH, I'm not sure the `published_at && expires_at && id` bit belongs in there (because `published_at`, `expires_at`, and `id` are all instance methods and you said you want a scope and a scope is in the class context). So, perhaps it's more like:

```
def active?
  where("published_at <= ? AND expires_at >= ?", DateTime.now, DateTime.now)
end
```

And, you said you want it to be a scope. So, I guess

```
scope :active?, -> { where("published_at <= ? AND expires_at >= ?", DateTime.now, DateTime.now) }
```

A scope is really just a class method. So, that could also be like:

```
class << self

  def active?
    where("published_at <= ? AND expires_at >= ?", DateTime.now, DateTime.now)
  end

end
```

...or:

```
def self.active?
  where("published_at <= ? AND expires_at >= ?", DateTime.now, DateTime.now)
end
```

...depending on what floats your boat.

Now, like I said, that's going to return an `ActiveRecord_Relation`, but doesn't do anything about sorting. I guess that would look like:

```
@posts =  current_user.
            posts.
            includes(:orgs).
            active?.
            order(created_at: :desc)
```

Personally, I think I would break that scope up to be more like:

```
class << self

  def active?
    published?.not_expired?
  end

  def published?
    where("published_at <= ?", DateTime.now)
  end

  def not_expired?
    where.not("expires_at <= ?", DateTime.now)
  end

end
```

'cause somewhere else you might want to use `published?` and `not_expired?`.

Comment: I personally don't like SQL in my code and would change for example `where("published_at <= ?", DateTime.now)` to `where(arel_table[:published_at].lteq(DateTime.now))`. Other than that I agree with the answer.